# Resize (Decrease) a char array using realloc and check for success

Tags: c, realloc

I've tried to initialize a dynamic `char` array, that decreases, if the string input from the user is smaller.

The problem is: I've got no idea, if the program is actually doing that? I get no error message and the right output, but is the unused memory really freed?

```
char *input=(char*)malloc(100);
gets(input);
int a = strlen(input);
input = realloc(input, a+1);
```

Comment: Never ***ever*** use `gets`. It's [a dangerous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) that have even been removed from the C standard.

Comment: Use a debugger...to find out.

Comment: As for your problem, it *might* be reallocated. Or it might not. You don't know, and it's not really relevant. However there's a very easy way to find out: If `realloc` returning the same pointer as `malloc` did? And related to that, don't forget to *always* assign the result of `realloc` to a new pointer, or you lose the original pointer if `realloc` returns `NULL`.

Comment: Well yes, the unused memory has been freed but you dont get to see it.

Comment: Why are you expecting an error message?

Answer (score 3):

Don't cast the result of `*alloc()` in C. Its not needed, only adds clutter to the code and in the worst case covers up errors like forgetting to `#inlude <stdlib.h>` for `*alloc()`.

The line

> ```
> input = realloc(input, a+1);
> ```

is problematic because you lose the previous pointer value if `realloc()` fails and returns `NULL`. Better:

```
char *new_input = realloc(input, a+1);
if(!new_input) {
    free(input);
    // print some error message
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

// everything fine:
input = new_input;

// use input

free(input);
```

---

PS: Also, as others have pointed out in the comments: Remove `gets()` from your vocabulary. Pretend it never existed. Use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: "Don't cast" - actually, oppinions about [differ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14879184/1312382) - maybe a minority, but a notable one... My personal recommendation to the topic: read and make up your own mind (or follow the rules of the project, if there are).

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the only way to check the success of the allocator functions would be to check for the returned pointer by the `realloc()` call against a `NULL` pointer. If the returned pointer is not `NULL`, you can be assured that the call is success.

Following the lines, the approach like

```
  pointer = realloc (pointer, newValue);
```

is problematic, as in case of `realloc()` failure, quoting from `C11`, chapter §7.22.3.5,

> [....] If memory for the new object cannot be
>   allocated, the old object is not deallocated and its value is unchanged.

and

> The `realloc` function returns a pointer to the new object (which may have the same
>   value as a pointer to the old object), or a null pointer if the new object could not be
>   allocated.

Thus, the returned null-pointer will overwrite the previous *valid* memory address and you'll lose the access and leak memory. The safe course of action is to

```
  type tempPOinter = NULL;
  tempPOinter = realloc(oldPointer, newSize);
  if (tempPOinter) {
      oldPointer = tempPOinter;
  }
  else {
     printf("Failure in realloc!!"); 
     free(oldPointer);
     return -1;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to change your algorithm.
In C, you can reserve a big-enough buffer on the stack, then after reading the input, allocate a permanent buffer on the heap:

```
#define BIG_ENOUGH 4096
char *get_line(FILE *fp)

{
    char buf[BIG_ENOUGH] = "";

    return fgets(buf, BIG_ENOUGH - 1, fp) ? strdup(buf) : NULL;
}
```

Comment: @machine_1: strdup() returns a pointer to an **allocates region of memory on the heap**, initialized with 'buf' (in our example). This code segment is just a hint for another algo. Regards...

Comment: Oops, on my android phone I did not see the strdup call. Sorry.